# How to make a bound service aware of any call to stopService() (even when bound)?

Tags: android, android-service

I've been through many posts about stopping bound services, but most are just misunderstandings of the Android API, and none answers my question. I didn't find the answer on the Android Developers website either (I might have missed something).

I have a service that can both be started and bound to.
I know that calls to `stopService()` won't stop my service if clients are still bound to it (therefore `onDestroy()` will not be called).

However, I would like to do something in the service when `stopService()` is called even if this does not stop it (because its 'started' behaviour is slightly different from its simple 'bound to' behaviour).

I know that `onStartCommand()` is called whenever `startService()` is called even if the service is already started, but `onCreate()` is called only once (when the service starts).

What I would like to have is a callback like `onStopCommand()`, which would be called whenever `stopService()` is called, even if `onDestroy()` is not called in the case of a still-bound service, but AFAIK this does not exist, does it?

The options I considered to solve my problem are the following, but I don't like either of them:

1. Split my service in 2 services (1 started, and 1 bound)
2. Implement a `stop()` method in my service that I should call everywhere just before `stopService()` (I could do that through the binder).

What do you think of these solutions? Do you have any better idea?

**EDIT: Here is a more detailed description of the differences between 'started' and 'bound to' behaviours of my service:**

Let's call my service S1. It contains a state that can be accessed from other activities and services by bounding to it. There is another service, S2, that can only be bound to.

When started through `startService()`, S1 binds to S2 to listen to events in S2 that can change the state in S1.

When stopped through `stopService()`, I would like S1 to unbind from S2 (and stop updating its state). For now I do it in `onDestroy()`.

My problem is that if clients are bound to S1, S1 won't stop and so won't unbind from S2.

I hope it helps understanding my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this does not exist, does it?

You are correct -- it does not exist.

> this does not exist, does it?

Both should work. It is difficult to indicate which might be preferable, since we do not know much about your app.

> Do you have any better idea?

Only use one or the other pattern. There is very little with services that requires both the command and the binding pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, I edited my post to detail a bit about the behaviour of the service.

Comment: @Joffrey: Create a single service that replaces S1 and S2 and does the work of both. Or, get rid of both services, as it is unclear why you need either of them. You do not need a service to maintain some sort of "state", nor do you need a service to propagate state changes -- use a `ContentProvider`, or a singleton and Otto, or something.

Comment: I cannot merge S1 and S2, since S2 is really independent and is used by several other components. In the first place, S1 was a singleton, but several reasons (that might have become obsolete now) led me to make it a service. I don't know much about `ContentProvider`s, but I'll look into it, thanks for the indication!